# How to upload picture to server WITHOUT using PHP and mySQL?

Tags: android

I'm here looking for ideas on how to upload the picture to the server **without** the used of PHP and mySQL?

I have build a camera2 api, but currently looking for a way to upload to a server **WITHOUT** the used of PHP and mySQL. But from the internet resource for example Volley, for my understanding it require PHP and mySQL in the server for retrieving and decode the picture purpose.

Anyone can share me ideas or documentation on the ways or methods that I can apply so that **without** the used of the database, PHP and mySQL.

Thanks

Comment: @NikolaLukic **without** using PHP and mySQL?

Comment: @CharlesShiller my condition now is , my requirement from the school that I cannot used the PHP and cannot used the mySQL, so any ideas on this?

Comment: I know there is POST function in the android , but I stuct on server there that I fail to receive picture without the used of mySQL and PHP

Comment: Sorry please...

Comment: Vivian there is no sense for this question . What about how to open socket without c++ ?!

Comment: What _can_ you use?

Comment: I can use Python only

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for Firebase.
We can develop serverless apps using Firebase
From realtime DB to file upload and notifications and much more.

https://firebase.google.com/products/

Comment: Hi, sorry to say that, I actually not allow to used any database in this project, which mean any picture taken will be direct store to the folder in server by the http link.

Comment: there is no way to store images in folder or something without having a backend structure or you can use some other language(java,python,nodejs) otherwise firebase if the last option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free image host like:

https://imgbb.com

[What's a good image hosting site with an API to allow me upload images from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642570/whats-a-good-image-hosting-site-with-an-api-to-allow-me-upload-images-from-my-w)